# Syntax error in jenkins

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins

I am executing one python script (which will internally run another python script) in my scp. It is working fine.

When I run the python script(**version2.7**)  in jenkins, I am getting a syntax error in one line of the internal python script:

**For example :**
I am running a.py .

Python ./folder/a.py

In a. py, i am executing another python script(b.py)

```
os.popen("python " + dir + "/../bin/b.py -i " + dependfile).read() 

b.py contains 

G = {'a': ['b'], 'c': ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']}

color = { u : "yellow" for u in G  }
```

I am getting below error :

```
color = { u : "yellow" for u in G  }

                            ^


SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am getting this error **only in jenkins** .

Comment: You're not running it under 2.7.

Comment: Can i know how to solve this

Comment: Run it under 2.7.

Comment: You should check which python version is actually installed on your jenkins server. A classic issue is having code execute successfully on a dvelopment machine, only to have it fail on the Jenkins server due to mismatching compiler versions. Assuming you are not using python 2.7 on your Jenkins server - simply upgrade you python installation to 2.7.

Comment: in jenkins , version is 2.6.6. In my scp , python version is 2.7.
But i don't have the permission to upgrade python version in jenkins

Comment: is there any similar command in python  that has the same functionality of  os.popen.read()

Comment: but i am os.popen in my other python script. it is working fine for those scripts

Comment: i tired using subprocess.call(). Still i am getting the same error message